# Rendering HTML via JS callback within R DT::datatables

Tags: javascript, html, r, dt

Working off of tomasreigl's example here (https://github.com/rstudio/DT/issues/393#issuecomment-279627237), I have a slight variation that is not working, I think due to basic JS issue.

**Create Data**

```
library(DT)
dataSet <- data.frame(name=c("Jack", "Jill"),
                  age=c(25,25),
                  tableHtml=c("<table><tr><th>Value A</th><th>Value B</th></tr><tr><td>1</td><td>2</td></tr></table>",
                              "<div><table><tr><th>Value A</th><th>Value B</th></tr><tr><td>3</td><td>4</td></tr></table></div>"),
                  stringsAsFactors=FALSE)'
```

**Approach 1, Render an HTML Table in the DT Table WORKING, But Not What I Need**

Now, what I would like to do is render an html table as a nested child for each row in the DT interactive table.  This first chunk works, but obviously will render the same table for each DT row, as the HTML is hard coded in the callback:

```
## Working, but same child table for every row
DT::datatable(
    cbind(' ' = '&oplus;', dataSet),
    escape = -2,
    options = list(
        columnDefs = list(
            list(visible = FALSE, targets = c(0,4)),
            list(orderable = FALSE, className = 'details-control', targets = 1)
        )
    ),
    callback = JS("
                  table.column(1).nodes().to$().css({cursor: 'pointer'});
                  var format = function(d) {
                    return '<div><table><tr><th>Value A</th><th>Value B</th></tr><tr><td>1</td><td>2</td></tr></table></div>'
                  };
                  table.on('click', 'td.details-control', function() {
                    var td = $(this), row = table.row(td.closest('tr'));
                      if (row.child.isShown()) {
                        row.child.hide();
                        td.html('&oplus;');
                      } else {
                        row.child(format(row.data())).show();
                        td.html('&CircleMinus;');
                      }
                    });"
                  )
)
```

**Approach 2 Render Different HTML Tables for each row NOT WORKING**

In comes the `tableHtml` column of the data frame `dataSet`.  For each row of data frame `dataSet` I would like to render a DT table row with a child row containing a table using the HTML in column `tableHtml` of data frame `dataSet`.  Below, I try just returning `d[4]`, but that returns the raw HTML without rendering the table.

```
## Attempt at different child table for each row
datatable(
    cbind(' ' = '&oplus;', dataSet),
    escape = -2,
    options = list(
        columnDefs = list(
            list(visible = FALSE, targets = c(0,4)),
            list(orderable = FALSE, className = 'details-control', targets = 1)
        )
    ),
    callback = JS("
                  table.column(1).nodes().to$().css({cursor: 'pointer'});
                  var format = function(d) {
                    return d[4]
                  };
                  table.on('click', 'td.details-control', function() {
                    var td = $(this), row = table.row(td.closest('tr'));
                      if (row.child.isShown()) {
                        row.child.hide();
                        td.html('&oplus;');
                      } else {
                        row.child(format(row.data())).show();
                        td.html('&CircleMinus;');
                      }
                    });"
                  )
)
```

I've tried about 20 variations but none of them work as expected.  The fact that my first modification of thomasreigl's example does work, makes me think it is just a minor JS issue that is beyond me.  Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, 2 more hours of fiddling and turns out changing `escape = -2` to `escape = FALSE` does the trick.